# url rewrite module patterns

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

i am using the Microsoft url rewrite module and i managed to get it to work successfully but i would like to use patterns like it should always rewrite url that look like this :

```
User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx
```

to this:

```
ahmed.aspx
```

how can i do that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article can help : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thank you for this but i am actually wondering if i can achieve this the default url rewrite module that comes with IIS 7 not with urlrewriter.net